# How to clone an array with length bigger than 32?

Tags: arrays, rust

A fixed-length array of a native type (or of a type that implements the `Copy` trait) can be cloned in Rust up to the length of 32. That is, this compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let source: [i32; 32] = [0; 32]; // length 32
    let _cloned = source.clone();
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
fn main() {
    let source: [i32; 33] = [0; 33]; // length 33
    let _cloned = source.clone(); // <-- compile error
}
```

In fact, the [trait `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) only declares a method for each generic array length, from 0 to 32.

What is an efficient and idiomatic way to clone a generic array of length, say, 33?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use a `Vec` in this case?

Comment: For anyone else going "WTF", [here is the implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.0.0/src/libcore/array.rs#L41)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add the `impl Clone` in your own code. This problem will be fixed at some point, in the mean time you can mostly work around it with varying amount of effort:

- If you just have a local variable of a concrete type and the type is `Copy` (as in your example), you can simply *copy* rather than *cloning*, i.e., `let _cloned = source;`.
- If the array is a field of a struct you want to implement `Clone` for (and `derive` won't work), you can still manually implement `Clone` and using the above trick in the implementation.
- Cloning an array of non-`Copy` types is trickier, because `Clone` can fail. You could write out `[x[0].clone(), x[1].clone(), ...]` for as many times as you need, it's a lot of work but at least it's certain to be correct.
- If all else fails, you can still create a newtype wrapper. This requires quite a bit of boilerplate to delegate all the other traits you need, but then you can (again, manually) implement `Clone`.

Answer (score 7):

You can clone arbitrary-length arrays since Rust 1.21.0. The "Libraries" section of the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1210-2017-10-12) says:

> Generate builtin impls for `Clone` for all arrays and tuples that are `T: Clone`