# Making an array of structs works only for some array sizes

Tags: arrays, struct, rust

I made a simple struct and implemented `Default` for it:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct LifeCell {
    state: usize
}

impl Default for LifeCell {
    fn default() -> LifeCell {
        LifeCell {
            state: 0
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create an array of such structs:

```
const TOTAL_CELLS: usize = 20;
let mut new_field: [[LifeCell; TOTAL_CELLS]; TOTAL_CELLS] = Default::default();
```

This compiles okay until I set `TOTAL_CELLS` to 35. Then it doesn't compile with an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[[LifeCell; 35]; 35]: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:14:65
   |
14 |     let mut new_field: [[LifeCell; TOTAL_CELLS]; TOTAL_CELLS] = Default::default();
   |                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `[[LifeCell; 35]; 35]`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'a [T] as std::default::Default>
             <&'a mut [T] as std::default::Default>
             <[T; 32] as std::default::Default>
             <[T; 31] as std::default::Default>
           and 31 others
   = note: required by `std::default::Default::default`
```

I know the reason for it - at the moment, the `Default` trait is implemented only for array sizes up to 32. But what should I do if I need an array of structs that is bigger than that?

I'm using Rust 1.18.0.

Comment: This one, among many others, emerge from the fact that arrays only implement certain traits for sizes up to 32, including `Default`.

Comment: @E_net4 is there any way to do something like that then? Without heap allocation preferebly?

Comment: `let mut new_field = [[LifeCell::default(); TOTAL_CELLS]; TOTAL_CELLS];`

Comment: @Shepmaster that does work, thank you! However, several problems arise afterwards with cloning that array and fitting it into another struct. Should I  ask another question or update this one?

Comment: You can't clone the array [for the same reasons and with the same workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30415354/155423). I'm not sure what you mean by "fitting it into". However, I'd encourage you to *not* try to put this on the stack. The 35-cell version takes up 9800 bytes! That's a pretty huge thing to have on the stack, passing as arguments, returning, etc. Instead, heap allocate it once and then just pass around slices to it (`&[[Cell; LEN]; LEN]`). You could even use a single `Vec` of length `LEN` * `LEN` and abstract away the x/y mapping in a new type.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you! By 'fitting in' I meant that that array was actually a part of another struct - which I couldn't create for the same reasons. But you are right, I should be using a single heap allocation anyway. Thanks again!